# should signals in vhdl be signed/unsigned to perform arithmetic operations?

Tags: vhdl, unsigned

I am practising some basic vhdl programs.Now i came across arithmetic operations.I used bit_vector and multiplied the input signals directly but it errors **"No feasible entries for infix operator"**.The program is below:

```
   entity multiplier is
   port(a,b : in bit_vector(3 downto 0);
   c: out bit_vector(7 downto 0));
   end  multiplier;

   architecture ar of multiplier is

   begin

   c<=(a*b);

   end ar;
```

But i came across this program which works fine with std_logic_vector

```
   library IEEE;
   use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
   use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
   entity Multiplier_VHDL is
   port(
  Nibble1, Nibble2: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  Result: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
  );
  end entity Multiplier_VHDL;

 architecture Behavioral of Multiplier_VHDL is
 begin

 Result <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(Nibble1) * unsigned(Nibble2));

 end ;
```

My questions are:

**1.cant we simply add 2 signal bits c<=a+b as we do in verilog?**

**2.should a signal be signed/unsigned to perform arithmetic operations?**

**3.like c which is signed by default,what about vhdl/verilog?**

**4.are signed & unsigned present in use ieee.std_logic_arith.all and use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL same?**

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Cant we simply add 2 signal bits `c <= a + b` as we do in verilog?

VHDL is a strongly typed language, which means it is strict when it comes to assigning things of different types to each other. Verilog might let you multiply a simple bit vector; you know what the types of the operands are and the format of the result, and that's fine  for your design process. In VHDL, it's not good enough that you as the designer know what formats the numbers are in, the compiler wants to know this as well. In your example, the compiler doesn't know if your vectors represent an unsigned number, signed, fixed point, etc. By casting them to unsigned, you are explicitly telling it what the number format is. An even better solution would be to have these as type `unsigned` throughout, to avoid the type casts.

Another advantage of VHDL strongly typed is that this can help to catch bugs caused by errors in number format storage at the compilation stage instead of under simulation or on an FPGA device. In general it saves time to catch bugs earlier in the design cycle. If you search online for "strongly typed" you will find more discussion on this topic.

### 2. Should a signal be signed/unsigned to perform arithmetic operations?

As above, if you want to stick to standard libraries, then yes it is a good idea to give your signals a meaningful type. Think about the guy trying to understand your code in 10 years time (it might even be you), if it's clear what the number formats are, their life will be made easier.

### 3. Like `c` which is signed by default, what about vhdl/verilog?

`c` in your example code is not signed by default in VHDL, it has whatever type you declared it as. If you are multiplying using `unsigned`, the result would also be `unsigned`, so this would be the type that I would use for the result. If the type of the result signal does not match the return type of the operation, this will be a compiler error.

### 4. Are `signed` & `unsigned` present in `use ieee.std_logic_arith.all` and use `IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL` same?

No, it is not recommended to use `std_logic_arith`, as this library is not part of the VHDL standard. If you familiarise yourself with the number formats in `numeric_std`, you should not need to use any other libraries for integer arithmetic.

Comment: Thank u jeff for the answer...I have 2 doubts..1.As u stated for the 1st question **the compiler doesn't know if your vectors represent an unsigned number, signed, fixed point, etc....**,but in verilog it compiles and executes well, so is verilog signed by default ?? 2.i think integer by default is signed.(bcoz i saw its default value to be -2145..... when adding integers a,b --->c<=a+b).so whats the trick to perform **unsigned integer**

Comment: I don't know about what Verilog would assume, sorry. If you want to add unsigned integers in VHDL, just declare the signals to have type `unsigned`

Answer (score 0):

The usual vector type to use in VHDL is `std_logic_vector` from the package `ieee.std_logic_1164`, instead of `bit_vector`.

However, this vector type is just a collection of `std_logic` elements, without defined arithmetic operations.  So the standard VHDL package that can be used to get arithmetic operations is `numeric_std`.

Using these for VHDL-2002 compatible code for unsigned arithmetic, it will look:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity multiplier is
  port(a, b : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
       c    : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end multiplier;

architecture ar of multiplier is
begin
  c <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) * unsigned(b));
end ar;
```

However, you could choose to define `a`, ´b´, and ´c´ as `unsigned` to simplify the code like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity multiplier is
  port(a, b : in  unsigned(3 downto 0);
       c    : out unsigned(7 downto 0));
end multiplier;

architecture ar of multiplier is
begin
  c <= a * b;
end ar;
```

There are also `signed` types defined in the `numeric_std` package.

In VHDL-2008, a `numeric_std_unsigned` package is provided, which provides arithmetic operations for the `std_logic_vector` type, thus the code can be like:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;

entity multiplier is
  port(a, b : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
       c    : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end multiplier;

architecture ar of multiplier is
begin
  c <= a * b;
end ar;
```

To answer the 4 questions:

1. Arithmetic operations must be defined for the operands, and this can be done either through use of conversion to `unsigned` type in `numeric_std` package, or through use of operators in `numeric_std_unsigned` package.
2. For VHDL-2002 yes, and for VHDL-2008 the `numeric_std_unsigned` package can be used.
3. See above.
4. The `std_logic_arith` package is a Synopsys package, so use `numeric_std` and `numeric_std_unsigned` instead.

Comment: Do you know what was the rationale for introducing `numeric_std_unsigned` into the standard? To me it is a regression, but I suppose there must be a good reason for it...

Comment: @scary_jeff: I assume the `numeric_std_unsigned` package was added to give a standard alternative to the very popular non-standard `std_logic_unsigned` package, but somebody following the VHDL standard development can better answer that.